# Zookeeper Refusing session request for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:59376 as it has seen zxid 0x124 our last zxid is 0x52 client must try another server

Tags: apache-zookeeper, telegraph

Running zookeeper with telegraph continue to get the following errors:

```
[2021-04-05 15:00:58,881] INFO Refusing session request for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:59376 as it has seen zxid 0x124 our last zxid is 0x52 client must try another server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-04-05 15:01:00,346] INFO Refusing session request for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:59378 as it has seen zxid 0x124 our last zxid is 0x52 client must try another server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-04-05 15:01:02,178] INFO Refusing session request for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:59380 as it has seen zxid 0x124 our last zxid is 0x52 client must try another server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-04-05 15:01:03,362] INFO Refusing session request for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:59382 as it has seen zxid 0x124 our last zxid is 0x52 client must try another server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-04-05 15:01:04,658] INFO Refusing session request for client /127.0.0.1:57084 as it has seen zxid 0x124 our last zxid is 0x52 client must try another server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-04-05 15:01:06,329] INFO Refusing session request for client /127.0.0.1:57086 as it has seen zxid 0x124 our last zxid is 0x52 client must try another server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-04-05 15:01:07,751] INFO Refusing session request for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:59388 as it has seen zxid 0x124 our last zxid is 0x52 client must try another server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-04-05 15:01:09,174] INFO Refusing session request for client /127.0.0.1:57090 as it has seen zxid 0x124 our last zxid is 0x52 client must try another server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-04-05 15:01:10,645] INFO Refusing session request for client /127.0.0.1:57092 as it has seen zxid 0x124 our last zxid is 0x52 client must try another server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-04-05 15:01:12,682] INFO Refusing session request for client /127.0.0.1:57094 as it has seen zxid 0x124 our last zxid is 0x52 client must try another server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
[2021-04-05 15:01:14,216] INFO Refusing session request for client /127.0.0.1:57096 as it has seen zxid 0x124 our last zxid is 0x52 client must try another server (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I ended up solving it by terminating all kafka clients i had. Not only containers but an UI as well. I was using Conduktor.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the client service. I hit the same issue and was able to resolve by restarting my docker container that was trying to connect to zookeeper.

The reason for this error is that your client is trying to connect with the transaction id it stored from the previous zookeeper session and when zookeeper goes down and comes back up it starts from a lower transaction id.